# Expected resource of type ID

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I am using `ANKO` to build simple project. When I try to set id for an `EditText` I am getting following error.

> Ensures that resource id's passed to APIs are of the right type; for example, calling `Resources.getColor(R.string.name)` is wrong.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import org.jetbrains.anko.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    relativeLayout {
        editText{
            id = 1
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: click here to view an error image format]

Comment: [youtube.com/watch?v=a0lxfdoOhSE&t=219s] can someone please tell me how he add id to edittext and I am trying to do same but getting an error. You can forward video to 8:00 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use id references (`R.id.something`) or negative integers from `-16777215` to `-1` (and ignore the warning).

Suitable negative integers can also be generated for you by using [`View.generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) method available since API 17. Source code is available [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.generateViewId%28%29). You'll have to remember the generated values yourself.

Generating an `R.id` is covered in other answers.

> I am trying to do same but getting an error

The video was published over a year ago and lint didn't warn you about Kotlin code back then.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an id as `R.id.some_name`

you can't pass **integers** on it.

**Example**:

```
editText {
        id = R.id.userNameEditText
        hintResource = R.string.create_user_hint_username
        textSize = 24f
      }
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Create an ids.xml file to generate the ids you require: https://developer.android.com/samples/BatchStepSensor/res/values/ids.html

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0lxfdoOhSE&t=219s]   can someone please tell me how he add id to edittext and I am trying to do same but getting an error

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a proper unique resource id for view's id and not just any int value.

First create a file [`ids.xml`](https://developer.android.com/samples/BatchStepSensor/res/values/ids.html) under `res/values/` and add an `id` for your `EditText`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="edit_text" type="id"/>

</resources>
```

Now use that as `EditText` `id`:

```
relativeLayout {
        editText{
            id = R.id.edit_text
        }
    }
```

Comment: [youtube.com/watch?v=a0lxfdoOhSE&t=219s] can someone please tell me how he add id to edittext and I am trying to do same but getting an error. You can forward video to 8:00 minutes

Comment: I am sure your method will work all I wonder is how he did in this video 
 [youtube.com/watch?v=a0lxfdoOhSE&t=219s]    can you please tell me how he adds an ID to `edittext` and I am trying to do same but getting an error. You can skip 8:00 minutes video.